# variations of the phrase 'I want to', 'I wish to' and 'I hope to'

Tags: phrase-request

I am currently writing a cover letter and noticed that I am using the three phrases to express that I want to do something if I join a company. It would be great if you can suggest some other ways to express 'I want / hope / wish to'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"want", "wish" and "hope" are quite different in color, remember that when using them.

As for the question:

1.I have a desire
2.It would be great if I
3.There wouldn't be a day I'd regret if
4.I am eager to
5.It would be a pleasure if (to)

There are quite a lot more.